# Pay toll to Rimini

Tags: italy, tolls, reggio-emilia

I'm heading to Rimini from Bosnia and Hercegovina and I know how much money I need for road toll in Croatia and Slovenia, but it's bit confusing when I look at Italy road tolls.

I'll be entering Italy from Slovenia place called Nova Gorica or Gorizia, and by my calculation's I will need about 20 euros in one direction, so 40 euros in both direction.

I'm I right about this, and if I'm not can someone help me and explain how can I calculate road toll in Italy, for this road section.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Travel SE! Your question is great and I upvote it, but it is basically two different questions, so can you please edit and post the second part as a different questions. Also your second question is very opinion-based and would likely be closed for this, can you make it as [on-topic](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as possible, e.g. asking for delicacies of Emilia-Romagna region? That should still be ok, but asking for restaurant recommendations is definitely off-topic here, I'm afraid!

Comment: ok no problem, I will edit it right now

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Toll will be about **29 euros**.
When entering the highway from Gorizia the first toll station is "Villesse". Then you travel towards Venezia Mestre, Padova, Bologna and then Rimini.
Exiting from "Rimini nord" (northern Rimini): 28.30 €
Exiting from "Rimini sud" (southern Rimini): 28.90 €

To calculate prices check this site:
http://www.infotraffico.autovie.it/Pedaggi
"Partenza" is the entrance in the highway, "Destinazione" is the exit.
Also [viamichelin.it](http://www.viamichelin.it/web/Itinerari?departure=34170%20Gorizia&departureId=31NDFodmgxMGNORFV1T1RReE5EYz1jTVRNdU5qSXhPRGc9&arrival=Rimini&arrivalId=3aMTEyaGMxMGNORFF1TURZd056ST1jTVRJdU5UWTJNVFU9&index=0&vehicle=0&type=1&distance=km&currency=EUR&avoidClosedRoad=false&motorway=false&toll=false&vignette=false&orc=false&crossing=true&caravan=false&car=hatchback&fuel=petrol&fuelCost=1.25&allowance=0&corridor=&departureDate=&arrivalDate=) gives you an estimate of prices. Highway and vignette prices are usually correct. (be careful as it sometimes suggests an itinerary out of the highway).

In Italy tolls are calculated on distance. You have to take a ticket from the machines when entering the highway. Keep the ticket and show it when exiting.
Some highways or part of them are free of charge (Trieste's "Fernetti" border to toll station "Trieste Lisert", which basically is Monfalcone; Gorizia to Villesse).

Some more suggestions for your trip:

Stop at a petrol station in Slovenia before entering Italy, petrol is much cheaper.

I don't know your travel plan, but I would suggest crossing the border towards Trieste (border Sežana/Fernetti). "Trieste Lisert" - "Rimini nord" costs 29 € and is faster as you practically never get out of the highway. Between Nova Goriza (Slovenia), Gorizia (Italy) and then the highway, you travel on regular roads.

In general you can pay using a Credit Card on toll stations that show this sign:
[image: Toll payment with Credit Cards in Italy]
Details: https://www.autostrade.it/en/il-pedaggio/pagamento-al-casello

Queues are generally shorter/faster. =)

Comment: So it's better to enter Italy from Trieste, I've was some how thinking the same thing, this route was suggested by `google maps`, I'll be using `HERE maps`  for this road trip, I will see what's `HERE` suggest, but now that I now I can plan on entering Italy from that direction. I know about the petrol, but thank you for the information, also I'm not usually trusting `viamichelin` it's good but  not that good, this kind an information is priceless, thank you.